# How to add classes to rendered content-div of ipBlock($block)->exampleContent('')->render($revisionId);

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, widget, impresspages

I am currently working on a Bootstrap collapsable-widget. 
Now I have this line to render the content of a collapse-panel:

```
<?php echo ipBlock($block)->exampleContent('')->render($revisionId); ?>
```

The output is like this:

```
<div id="ipBlock-nested1043_1_" data-revisionid="191" 
  data-languageid="0" class="ipBlock">
```

So far so nice. 
But how can I add a class after 'ipBlock' which is set by the block.php inside the view folder of the IP core (IP 4.2.7)?

I need something like this:

```
<div id="ipBlock-nested1043_1_" data-revisionid="191" 
  data-languageid="0" class="panel-collapse collapse ipBlock">
```

I aleady thought about adopting via a php file in the widget's view folder but that does not seem to be the right approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can override block view as any other view on ImpressPages http://www.impresspages.org/docs/view